# C++ : How to initialize an object that uses two header files?

Tags: c++, initialization, header-files

I am having trouble with initializing an object that uses two header files. One header file stacks values into an array which is made from the other header file. I use a separate main script to do calculations with a Stack definition file. It looks as follow:

Main script

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Array.h"

using namespace std ;

int main() {

int LEN = 10;               // size array
double def_val = 1.1 ;      // a default value that is used to fill a resized array

Stack s(LEN, def_val) ;     // <--- causing compiler error

// Do calculations with functions defined in a Stack.cc file

return 0;
}
```

Stack header file

```
#ifndef STACK_HH 
#define STACK_HH

#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

using namespace std ;

class Stack {

    public: 
        Stack(int size, double value) {
            s.size(size);
            s.value(value);    // <--- Not sure if I should use this, see Array header file how default value is used to resize an array
            count = 0

            //used member functions which are not important to solve this particular problem
        }

    // Member functions

    private:
       Array<double> s ;
       int count ;
};
```

Array header file

```
#ifndef ARRAY_HH
#define ARRAY_HH

template <class T> 
class Array {
public:

  Array(int size, T value) : _size(size) {         // <--- takes two arguments
     _arr = new T[_size] ;
     _value = value ;       // Set default value
     std::cout << "default value = " << _value << std::endl ;
  }


  Array(const Array<T>& other) : _size(other._size), _value(other._value) {
    _arr = new T[other._size] ;
    _value = _value ;       

    // Copy elements
    for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++) {
        _arr[i] = other._arr[i] ;
    }

  }

 ~Array() {
    delete[] _arr ;
  }


  Array<T>& operator=(const Array<T>& other) {
    if (&other==this) return *this ;
    if (_size != other._size) {
       resize(other._size) ;
    }
    for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++) {
       _arr[i] = other._arr[i] ;
    }
    return *this ;
  }

  T& operator[](int index) {
      if (index > _size) {          
          resize(index) ;
      }
      return _arr[index] ;
   }

  const T& operator[](int index) const {
      if (index > _size) {          
         resize(index) ;
      }
      return _arr[index] ;
  }

 int size() const { return _size ; }
 T value() const { return _value ; }   // <--- Included this for reading the default value from the object initialized in the main script, just like the size is read.

 void resize(int newSize) {
    // Allocate new array
    T* newArr = new T[newSize] ;

    // Copy elements
    for (int i=0 ; i<_size ; i++) {
        newArr[i] = _arr[i] ;
    }

    // Fill remaining array with default value
    for (int i=_size ; i<=newSize; i++){
        newArr[i] = _value ;
    }

    // Delete old array and install new one
    delete[] _arr ;
    _size = newSize ;
    _arr = newArr ;

 }


private:
  int _size ;
  T* _arr ;
  T _value ;
} ;

#endif
```

When compiling I get the error that no matching function can be called for 
"Array[double]::Array()" when Stack(int size, double value) { } is being read in the Stack.h file.

Initially, only the size was being read. However, I realized the Array header file needs a second argument to make an array. So I included the s.value() function in the Stack.h file similar to the s.size() one. Yet this didn't solve the compiler error.

This is a modified version of an already working script I made two weeks ago but now want to extend its usability and turn it into a template class.

Please don't mind my English.

EDIT:

I thank you both. This was indeed causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you haven't specified a default constructor (`Array::Array()`) for Array and when the compiler sees this:

```
    Stack(int size, double value) {
        s.size(size);
        s.value(value);    // <--- Not sure if I should use this, see Array header file how default value is used to resize an array
        count = 0

        //used member functions which are not important to solve this particular problem
    }
```

what you have actually written is:

```
    Stack(int size, double value)
        : s()  // default initialize s
        , count()  // default initialize count
    {
        s.size(size);
        s.value(value);    // <--- Not sure if I should use this, see Array header file how default value is used to resize an array
        count = 0

        //used member functions which are not important to solve this particular problem
    }
```

The `s()` fails because this is a default-construction of Array and there is no default constructor for Array.

EDIT:
As hr_117 points out, you can solve this either by adding a default ctor to Array or you could add the following initialization to Stack:

```
    Stack(int size, double value)
        : s(size, value)  // default initialize s
        , count(0)  // default initialize count
    {
    }
```

Comment: Seems that what he shuld do /  like to do is `Stack(int size, double value)
        : s(size, value) ` ...